# Android sdk installation. Error: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, sdk, ubuntu-14.04

I am setting up eclipse and the Android sdk environment on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) tutorial exactly and now I am almost at the end, but I get this "no child element is expected at this point"

What do I need to do?

I am new to Linux, and yes I have looked up the answer to this already, but the answer I found doesn't seem to match up with what I need exactly and since I am a new user, I can't figure this out on my own.

Comment: Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started/30440239#30440239

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed thank you so much

Comment: Incase anyone else wants it, i have pasted it as answer, accept it if it worked for you.. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution is to remove package **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image** available under **Android 5.1.1 (API 22)** to resolve this problem.

Reference - [Error Loading the sdk when eclipse is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started#30439524)

Comment: Well, if you need this emulator for running wear, then it's not really a solution to remove it. The wear arm system image works fine on Android Studio, so if you need the api level 22 image for wear development, then consider switching from Eclipse to Android Studio, which makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just open the **Android SDK Manager** and delete ***both*** the **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image**  and **Androi Wear Intel x86 Atom SystemImage** under **Android 5.1.1 (API 22)**

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Android Wear package from SDK manager And restart the eclipse

package (i) Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image(5.1 API 22)
(ii) Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image(5.1 API 22)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by providing comment to d:skin element.open XML file from eclipse then then give comment using  sysntax.

XML file is stored in system images package(android wear/armeabi-v7a and x86)

Instead of deleting XML file it is better option.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, actually, this is what I ended up doing after thinking about it for a while

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "Android Wear" folder from the below path:

```
C:\Users\amreen.s(your user folder name)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the default devices.xml file from : /home/user/android-sdk/tools/lib/devices.xml

and paste it in the below paths: /android-sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/ and /android-sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/

This is a alternative solution, however, before replacing the devices.xml, take backup of the existing devices.xml file in these folders.